# How to implement Animations for Private Routes in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, routes, react-router

I am trying to find the library for animating rendering of different private routes in react js. I only found the CSS transition group but they are useful only with open routes. So is there a library to animate private routes in React JS

Answer (score 0):

In constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
         loading: true
    }
}
```

In componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({
       loading: false
   })
}
```

In render

```
render() {
     return this.state.loading ? 
           <YOUR_ANIMATION_COMPONENT />
           : <YOUR_ROOT_COMPONENT />
}
```